# Redshift: Detect and Cancel Long running queries Per User Connection

Tags: postgresql, amazon-redshift, metabase

I am running Redshift queries with Metabase as the front end. I want to detect and cancel long running queries for a particular user. How do I automate this process with a script?

Comment: Did you end up using the WLM queue rules? I notice Metabase has a cancel button but doesn't seem to actually send a cancel to Redshift; queries continue to run.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be set as cluster configuration parameter on cluster or workload level. Workload is a separate query queue that is associated to specific users and defines the amount of cluster resources that is allowed to consume.

Read more about query timeouts here: [statement_timeout](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_statement_timeout.html) and [WLM Timeout](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/cm-c-defining-query-queues.html#wlm-timeout)

General info about workload management here: [Configuring Workload Management](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/mgmt/workload-mgmt-config.html)

Answer (score 4):

Write a script and query the [**stv_recents**](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_STV_RECENTS.html) table. It has `pid` and `duration` (in microseconds).

If a query crosses the threshold (in terms of duration), execute 
`cancel pid`.

You may put this script in a crontab and execute it at regular intervals.

Comment: Have you done that? Sounds a bit brutal, maybe restrict it to certain logins

Comment: @Davos Yes, had to implement this. Some business users simply don't understand the concept of partitions, indexing, cross joins etc. To keep resources consumed under check, the best way is to cancel such jobs [queries] which drain the resources, intimate them and if the trend continues, deactivate the account.

Comment: I'd say none understand :) Have you looked into the WLM queue rules? It could do this without needing a service to run a script. It has things like `nested_loop_join_row_count` to protect against cartesian products and other naive / greedy queries. I'm starting to agree with you that just killing rogue queries is the best kind of feedback to users who don't have visibility over the impact of their usage and the limited concurrency of Redshift.

Comment: I tried to understand the trend. Some of the users do understand the concepts but have such business requirements that they have to do an FTS or some other weird practices and you can't deny them, because, ahem, they are the business users. I tried to generalise things by setting system parameters but then I realised there are a lot of usecases, exceptions etc. It is then I decided to write a script accessing a metadata where all such exceptions and approvals are available. The script takes care of each and every user in a dynamic (personalised) way w/o fudging the system parameters :)

Answer (score 2):

There is no need to write this yourself!

You can use Redshift's built in Query Monitoring Rules ("QMR") to control queries according to a number of metrics such as `return_row_count`, `query_execution_time`, and `query_blocks_read` (among others).

Queries that exceed the limits defined in your rules can either `log` (no action), `hop` (move to a different queue), or `abort` (kill the query).

You can learn more in the Redshift Docs: ["WLM Query Monitoring Rules"](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/cm-c-wlm-query-monitoring-rules.html)

Comment: Do you have any recommended settings you use? I see the templates there are interesting. I feel like I would just have to guess at what is reasonable and then tweak it until the limits are right which seems time consuming.

Comment: You can use the view "wlm_qmr_rule_candidates.sql" from our Redshift Utils repo as a starting point. https://github.com/awslabs/amazon-redshift-utils/blob/a36138f34052e3a6d9072a4da9e46107da4eacd0/src/AdminScripts/wlm_qmr_rule_candidates.sql

Answer (score 0):

In redshift under WML, edit workload queue and under it add custom rule define query execution type and action you want to execute.